# Dealing with uncommon date structures in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data set and it contains the following variable for date.

```
dat$Leads_MONTH
 [1] "10-Jan" "10-Feb" "10-Mar" "10-Apr" "10-May" "10-Jun" "10-Jul" "10-Aug" "10-Sep" "10-Oct" "10-Nov" "10-Dec" "11-Jan" "11-Feb" "11-Mar" "11-Apr"
[17] "11-May" "11-Jun" "11-Jul" "11-Aug" "11-Sep" "11-Oct" "11-Nov" "11-Dec" "12-Jan" "12-Feb" "12-Mar" "12-Apr" "12-May" "12-Jun" "12-Jul" "12-Aug"
[33] "12-Sep" "12-Oct" "12-Nov" "12-Dec" "13-Jan" "13-Feb" "13-Mar" "13-Apr" "13-May" "13-Jun" "13-Jul"
```

I want to plot this data on the x axis using ggplot2 but am having some issues with this task. Is there a way to get ggplot2 to format Leads_MONTH as a date format and then plot it using ggplot2.

```
ggplot(dat, aes(Leads_MONTH, LEADSforester)) +
   geom_bar(stat="identity", fill="#336699") + 
     theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

The above code produces a plot but the dates on the x axis are not in the write order.

I tried to set the variable as a date but am not having any luck.

```
> dat$Leads_MONTH <- as.Date(dat$Leads_MONTH)
Error in charToDate(x) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the bar plot, you can manually convert Leads_MONTH to factor and specify the levels.

```
dat <- data.frame(Leads_MONTH = c(
"10-Jan", "10-Feb", "10-Mar", "10-Apr", "10-May", "10-Jun", "10-Jul", "10-Aug", "10-Sep", "10-Oct", "10-Nov", "10-Dec", "11-Jan", "11-Feb", "11-Mar", "11-Apr",
"11-May", "11-Jun", "11-Jul", "11-Aug", "11-Sep", "11-Oct", "11-Nov", "11-Dec", "12-Jan", "12-Feb", "12-Mar", "12-Apr", "12-May", "12-Jun", "12-Jul", "12-Aug",
"12-Sep", "12-Oct", "12-Nov", "12-Dec", "13-Jan", "13-Feb", "13-Mar", "13-Apr", "13-May", "13-Jun", "13-Jul"),
LEADSforester = runif(43))

library(ggplot2)
# Convert Leads_MONTH to factor and specify the levels
dat$Leads_MONTH <- factor(dat$Leads_MONTH, levels = dat$Leads_MONTH)
ggplot(dat, aes(Leads_MONTH, LEADSforester)) +
   geom_bar(stat="identity", fill="#336699") + 
     theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

If you want to convert into Date class, you need to add day and specify the argument format

```
as.Date(paste0(dat$Leads_MONTH, '-1'), format = '%y-%b-%d')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
library(zoo)
as.yearmon(dat$Leads_MONTH, format="%y-%b")
```

To convert them to normal date objects wrap that in `as.Date`

Comment: Also note that zoo has `scale_x_yearmon()`